# c++ operator << for typedef within class

Tags: c++, class, typedef, operator-keyword

I plan to use overloaded operators in a c++ class but not as member functions. The problem is that the operators should not work on the data type defined by the class itself rather on typedefs defined within the class. 
An excerpt of my code is as follows:

The class definition in the header file:

```
namespace myspace
{
 class Exporter{
 public:
      Exporter(const Markov & MP);
      Exporter(const Network & net);
      ~Exporter();
      void Export(std::string filename);
      typedef std::vector<int> pvi;
      typedef std::vector<std::string> pvs;
 protected:
      void Export1(std::string filename, pvs Mydata);
      void Export2(std::string filename, pvi Mydata2);
      // Helper functions
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const pvi& vi);
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const pvs& vi);
      ...
 private:
      pvs Data1;
      pvi Data2;
       ...
 };
}
```

The implementation in a cpp file:

```
using namespace myspace;
//===============================================================================
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Exporter::pvi& vi)
{
  os << "(";
  std::copy(vi.begin(), vi.end()-1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, ","));
  std::copy(vi.end()-1, vi.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os));
  os << ")";
  return os;
}
//===============================================================================
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Exporter::pvs& vi)
{
  os << "(";
  std::copy(vi.begin(), vi.end()-1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, ","));
  std::copy(vi.end()-1, vi.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os));
  os << ")";
  return os;
}
//===============================================================================
void  Exporter::Export(std::string filename)
{
      Export1(std::string filename, Data1);
      Export2(std::string filename, Data2);
}
//==============================================================================
void  Exporter::Exporter1(std::string filename,pvs Mydata_s)
{
      std::ofstream outf;
      outf.open(filename.c_str());
      outf << Mydata_s << "\n";
      outf.close();
}
//==============================================================================
void  Exporter::Exporter2(std::string filename,pvi Mydata_i)
{
      std::ofstream outf;
      outf.open(filename.c_str());
      outf << Mydata_i << "\n";
      outf.close();
}
//==============================================================================
```

During compilation no warnings and errors referring the operators are generated. But the output doesn't seems to be formated thus it looks like that the standard / default  operators are used.

Are there any hints or suggestions how to overcome that?

Comment: `typedef std::vector pvi;` should not compile.

Comment: @user3522891 what do you mean by `the output doesn't seems to be formated` ? Can you give a use case for the operators ?

Comment: You can't normally stream a vector at all, so if you're compiling and seeing any output, it's from those functions and the formatting issues are yours.  Your operators are broken for empty vectors due to the -1 hack.  Unintended string content could make it look "unformatted".  Further, typedefs don't create distinct types - this can't scale once you have vectors with the same element type.  Exporter functions should take vectors by const reference to avoid wasting time copying.

Comment: @alf its a typdef std::vector<int> pvi

Comment: @Raxvan I've to format the data stored in the vectors as input for another software. The default operator doesn't do that in a sufficient way. Especially for the vector there is either some overhead (e.g. vector length) written. Beyond that some separators are missing.are missing.